React returns empty array from hook
I try to delete data from an List. The List is just for rendering because the data where deleted by API.
But when i call the list, it will return a empty array instead of the data is have in my table rendert.
Now i don't know why my list is empty. I need to filter it after i deleted the data in my database.
Here my Component:
import './user.css';

import { useImmer } from "use-immer";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "ag-grid-community/styles/ag-grid.css";
import 'ag-grid-community/styles/ag-theme-quartz.css';
import { AgGridReact } from 'ag-grid-react';
import { ColDef } from 'ag-grid-community';
import { AG_GRID_LOCALE_DE } from '../../utils/agGridLocale-de.ts'
import LoadingScreen from "../loadData.tsx";
import api from "../../config.ts";
import { IUser } from "../../models/user.ts";

const USER_URL = '/user';

const UserList = () => {
    const deleteButton = (props: any) => {
        const { _id } = props.data;
        return (
            <button className='btn btn-table-delete' onClick={() => deleteUser(_id)}><i className="bi bi-trash3-fill"></i></button>
        )
    }
    
    const deleteUser = async (userId: string) => {
        if (!window.confirm('Benutzer wirklich löschen?')) {
            return;
        }
        try {
            // userList is empty here
            console.log(userList);
            
            /* This part is working fine except the part of "setUserList" -> Will clear my table because userList is empty here*/

            // await api.delete(`${USER_URL}/${userId}`)
            // .then(response => {
            //     console.log(response);
            // })
            // .then(() => {
            //     setUserList(userList.filter(user => user._id !== userId));
            // })
            // .catch(error => {
            //     console.error(error);
            // });
        } catch (error: any) {
            console.error(error);
        }
    }
                
    const [ userList, setUserList ] = useImmer<IUser[]>([]);
    const [ loading, setLoading ] = useState(true);
    const [ error, setError ] = useState({ name: '', message: '' });
    
    useEffect(() => {
        let isMounted = true;
        const abortController = new AbortController();
        
        const getUsers = async () => {
            try {
                isMounted && await api.get(USER_URL, { signal: abortController.signal })
                .then(response => {
                    setUserList(response.data);
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    if (error.name !== 'CanceledError'){                        
                        setError({ name: error.name, message: error.message });
                    }
                })
                .finally(() => {
                    setLoading(false);
                });
            } catch (error: any) {
                if (error.name !== 'CanceledError'){                        
                    setError({ name: error.name, message: error.message });
                }            
            }
        }
        getUsers();
        
        return () => {
            isMounted = false;
            abortController.abort();
        }
    }, [setUserList]);


    const [ colDefs ] = useImmer<ColDef<IUser>[]>([
        { headerName: 'ID', field: '_id'},
        { headerName: 'Vorname', field: 'firstName'},
        { headerName: 'Nachname', field: 'lastName'},
        { headerName: 'Benutzername', field: 'username'},
        { headerName: 'Rolle', field: 'role'},
        { headerName: 'Aktiv', field: 'isActive', cellClass: 'ag-grid-cell-center' },
        { cellRenderer: deleteButton, filter: false, sortable: false, cellClass: 'ag-grid-cell-center' },
    ]);
    
    const [ defaultColDef ] = useImmer<ColDef<IUser>>({
        sortable: true,
        filter: true,
        flex: 1,
        minWidth: 100,
        filterParams: {
            buttons: ['reset'],
            closeOnReset: true,
            filterOptions: ['contains'],
            trimInoput: true,
        },
    });
    
    const gridOptions = {
        localeText: AG_GRID_LOCALE_DE,
    }
        
        
    return (
        <>
            {loading && <LoadingScreen />}
            {error.name && 
                <div>
                    <p>Es ist ein Fehler aufgetreten: {error.name}</p>
                    <p>Message: {error.message}</p>
                </div>
            }

            <h3>Benutzer</h3>
            <div className='ag-theme-quartz-dark' style={{height: '30vh'}}>
                <AgGridReact 
                    rowData={userList}
                    columnDefs={colDefs}
                    defaultColDef={defaultColDef}
                    gridOptions={gridOptions}
                    pagination={true}
                    paginationPageSize={10}
                    paginationPageSizeSelector={[5, 10, 50, userList.length > 0 ? userList.length : 1]}
                    />
            </div>
        </>
    )
}

export default UserList;


I want to do:
setUserList(userList.filter(user => user._id !== userId));

user._id is perfectly there. But filtering a empty array returns oviously an empty array...
So how can i get the userList with it's actual rendert data?
Info:

App React
Api Express
Fetch with Axios

I try to load the data not async (for fetching and deleteUser()).
I try to debug in browser to see where the list is cleared, but dont found it.
I try to use useState instead of useImmer
I try to set default Data in useImmer hook like so:
const [ userList, setUserList ] = useImmer<IUser[]>([
        {
            _id: '',
            firstName: '',
            lastName: '',
            username: '',
            role: '',
            isActive: false,
    ]);

Then i become all time this data back with a console.log(userList);

I solved it!
The trick was to change from useImmer to useMemo for the colDefs and defaultColDef.
